# Verify inside input if value is over max

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a data table that I render in ASP.NET MVC using C# in a razor view.

To make a really short example of what I'm trying to achieve let's use this table as an example.

```js
function setValueAttr(el) {
  el.setAttribute('value', el.value)
}

function aplicar() {
  var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
  var tableData = [];
  Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
    var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
    var obj = {};
    obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
    obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
    obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
    obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
    obj.E = input.value;
    tableData.push(obj);
  });
  console.log(tableData);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" value="" min="0" max="1000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" value="" min="0" max="1000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" value="" min="0" max="1000"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="aplicar()">Aplicar</button>
</form>
```

What this does is that it will pull data out of the rows that do have data inside the last input in the column E into an array

However I can input any amount of data even if I setup the attribute `max="1000"` on all of my inputs, how I can solve this?

In the MVC view instead of the static max value I have on this example I have a `foreach` for a data table that I get from a dataset, declaring it inside as `@my_value` will output different values inside the `max=""` attribute however this won't stop me from writing any value just like in this example

Comment: The `max` attribute doesn't prevent you from manually setting the value over the maximum; it just marks the input as invalid. If you change the selector you pass to `querySelectorAll` to include `:valid` at the end, and enter values above `max` in all of the fields, it will return an empty array.

Comment: What's the syntax to add that :valid at the end of the querySelectorAll ?

Comment: Literally, just add it to the end of the selector: `document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""]):valid');`

Comment: That worked, btw can you link me where can I learn to put code like you edited my post like using the "Run Code Snippet" and also adding code-background to your comments? Also, thanks for the answer

Comment: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)

Comment: Thanks again, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this attribute

```
var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""]):valid');
```

And it fixed it, thanks a lot everyone, specially @HereticMonkey who solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple addition to your script function to check for max. I think unless you use observers you will have to check in your javasctipt

```
function aplicar() {
            var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
            var tableData = [];
            Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
                var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
                var obj = {};
                obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
                obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
                obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
                obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
                if(input.value > MAX)
                {
                    input.value = MAX;
                }
                obj.E = input.value;
                tableData.push(obj);
            });
            console.log(tableData);
        }
```

Comment: How do I point the javascript variable MAX to my html <input max="value"> value?

Comment: You could create a dictionary with the key being the id of the input and the value being your max value. This way each input can have separate max values.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attribute value with javascript is most likely circumventing the validation mechanism of the input element. Why do you set the value element using javascript? The value attribute is filled by typing a value into the input element by itself.